# Query from two tables have two different date fields

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two tables one for receiving "PO_RECVR_HIST" and other table for sales "PS_TKT_HIST_LIN". I want to create a query showing the total for receiving and total for sales. The two dates are not related the results come wrong.  The two tables has the same vendor. I am using the following query

```
SELECT P.VEND_NO,
       sum(P.RECVR_TOT)AS RECV_TOT,
       sum(S.CALC_EXT_PRC) AS SAL_TOT    
FROM PO_RECVR_HIST P INNER JOIN
     PS_TKT_HIST_LIN S
     ON P.VEND_NO = S.ITEM_VEND_NO
WHERE P.RECVR_DAT > getdate()-7   
GROUP BY P.VEND_NO, S.BUS_DAT    
HAVING S.BUS_DAT > getdate()-7    
ORDER BY P.VEND_NO
```

Any advise please?

Comment: Please fix your formatting.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: What do you mean "two dates are not related"? Where are you selecting the S.date?

Comment: Use [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/) for demo

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product (and your query uses non-standard SQL). Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using

Comment: It is sql server

Answer (score 0):

I think I get it.  You want the sums in different columns.  One approach is to do a `UNION ALL` to get the data together, and then aggregate:

```
SELECT VEND_NO,
       SUM(RECVR_TOT)AS RECV_TOT,
       SUM(CALC_EXT_PRC) AS SAL_TOT    
FROM ((SELECT P.VEND_NO, P.RECVR_DAT as dte, P.RECVR_TOT, 0 as CALC_EXT_PRC 
       FROM PO_RECVR_HIST P
      ) UNION ALL
      (SELECT S.ITEM_VEND_NO, S.BUS_DAT, 0, CALC_EXT_PRC
       FROM PS_TKT_HIST_LIN S
      )
     ) PS
WHERE DTE > GETDATE() - 7   
GROUP BY P.VEND_NO   
ORDER BY P.VEND_NO;
```

A `JOIN` is just not a good approach because it will throw off the aggregation.

Comment: It gives error message "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ON'.

Comment: They are two tables with two different date columns (received date and sales date) I want to calculate the total received from received table and total sales from sales table for the period of last week, month to date, year to date